# filter igraph object by vertex attribute value

Tags: r, filter, igraph, data-manipulation, adjacency-matrix

`mymatrix` is an igraph object (weighted adjacency matrix):

```
> summary(mymatrix)
IGRAPH 14317c4 UNW- 810 8761 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), year (v/n), bad (v/n), new (v/n), weight (e/n)
```

One of the node attributes is `year`:

```
> summary(V(mymatrix)$year)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1990    2011    2014    2013    2017    2019
```

`newmatrix` is an igraph object that only includes nodes associated with a given year. If the value of `year` is greater than 2013, I want to remove the node from both the row and column of the matrix prior to graphing and analysis.

I tried to use `filter()` in the dplyr package and get the following error:

```
> newmatrix<-filter(mymatrix, V(mymatrix)$year<2013)
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "igraph"
```

One work-around is modifying the data I used to produce the adjacency matrix in the first place. But I wanted to know if there was a way to filter igraph objects by node attributes that I haven't found in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like

```
delete_vertices(mymatrix, V(mymatrix)$year >= 2013)
```

should give the expected graph.